# How to get more than one Array in a picker view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarraycontroller, picker

Im really close on this one...For the purposes of this i have two text boxes. when pressed they invoke a ui picker.

text box one returns values 1,2,3,4

text box two returns values A, B, C, D

The problem is that when the picker is presented for text box two it shows the values from text box one, although will select the appropriate row from text box two.  Could someone check over my code and tell me where im making an error, thanks.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,     UIPickerViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>

{
//decalre picker
UIPickerView *select;



//declare NSArrray
NSArray *arrStatus;
NSArray *arrStatus2;


}






@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *text1;
- (IBAction)Value:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *text2;


@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize text2;

@synthesize text1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{



select = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
select.delegate = self;
select.dataSource = self;
[select setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
text1.inputView = select;
text2.inputView = select;     


arrStatus = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",nil];
arrStatus2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",nil];


-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
//One column
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
//set number of rows
return arrStatus.count;
return arrStatus2.count;

}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
//set item per row
return [arrStatus objectAtIndex:row];
return [arrStatus2 objectAtIndex:row];



[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

 - (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setText1:nil];
[self setText2:nil];

[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)Value:(id)sender {




NSInteger selectedRow = [select selectedRowInComponent:0];

if([text1 isFirstResponder])
text1.text = [arrStatus objectAtIndex: selectedRow];
[text1 resignFirstResponder];

if ([text2 isFirstResponder])
text2.text = [arrStatus2 objectAtIndex: selectedRow];
[text2 resignFirstResponder];


}

@end
```

So to sum up im trying to get, 1 picker view, with 1 colum, 2 arrays, 2 text boxes.  Ive tried creating another picker view and that didnt work either

Comment: Try to use a `NSDictionary` to index your data, then you can send both `"1"` and `"A"` in the return.

Comment: Ive taken everyones comments on board, adjusted my code.  However, whichever text box is presented first, That array is then displayed for the other text box even though it will select an object from the other NSArray.   Heres an example http://cl.ly/1v2B0Q3I3D1H

Comment: Thanks NSPunk, be gentle if ive done something silly.

Comment: i couldn't run that code.. can you fix it for just display the app?

Answer (score 3):

The `return`  statement exits the method. Therefore , if you have 2 `return` statements , it will never get to the second one. You should modify these methods as such:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
    if([text1 isFirstResponder])
        return arrStatus.count;
    else
        return arrStatus2.count;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
     if([text1 isFirstResponder])
         return [arrStatus objectAtIndex:row];
     else
         return [arrStatus2 objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thanks fo reply, all that does is presents the same NSArray for both boxes again but will allow me bring up second NSArray for both boxes instead of just the first.  How do I populate 1 picker with more than one array for each text box?

Comment: In the first method above you have to specify the number of entries in the pickerView. If you want multiple arrays there ,just use array1.count + array2.count etc . In the second method check `if(row < array1.count) return [array1 objectAtIndex:row]; else return [array2 objectAtIndex:row - array1.count];` etc. This should also be used in the didSelectRow method. Hope this helps.

Comment: made a test app using your suggestions to show you http://cl.ly/0z370Y3o0M1z Im obviously missing something

Answer (score 0):

This is Code Which is able to show picker view with the given array and textfield will have the first data of the **UIPickerView**.Please let me know if you have any issue.I did it for one textfield for next textfield you just need to figure out using tag of textfield and set the Text.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        arrayNo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",nil];
        [pickerView selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
        self.text1.text= [arrayNo objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    mlabel.text=    [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [arrayNo count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Comment: its picking the object form the second NSArray, I just cant seem to present the objects in the picker view